# Trying to test unicode filename retrieval/conversion to/from UTF8-UTF16

Tags: c++, unicode

I've looked at a lot of examples for WideCharToMultiByte, etc.  This question is more about testing.

I downloaded another language set, Chinese, Simplified China to my machine.  Then using the virtual keyboard I created a directory on C:\ with some Chinese characters in the path, and placed a file inside the directory.

I'm trying to see that I get the correct filename by testing _wfopen with my path.  I also have the same file in another location for testing:

```
  //setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh-CN");
  //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Chinese_China.936");
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  wchar_t* outfilename = L"C:\\特殊他\\和阿涛和润\\bracket3holes.sat";
  //wchar_t* outfilename = L"C:\\heather\\bracket3holes.sat";
  wchar_t w[] = L"r";
  FILE* foo = _wfopen(outfilename, w);
```

First I tried without setting locale, then I tried various combinations of setting locale to the language I downloaded (therefore the language of the path).
_wfopen works fine with the C:\heather path, but always returns a NULL pointer with the unicode path.

What am I missing?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Note my code must be compilable back to vc9.

--- Based on the feedback, I saved the file as UTF-8 with BOM, added const before the wchar_t declarations, and now in the debugger I do see the right string and the file pointer is no longer null.

Thank you for your help.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around this all, we're trying to transition from const char* to unicode-friendly.

Comment: I think there is an issue with placing foreign characters inside a source file like that.  What you see in the editor is not necessarily what is being compiled.

Comment: Assigninig string literals to non-const pointers is a recipe for desaster. Don't even start with that. That said, please provide a full example including (!) the exact encoding of the sourcefile and the compiler commandline. FYI: Modern MS Windows filesystems use UTF-16 as file encoding, which means you can use any Unicode filename (properly encoded, of course) regardless of the locale. In other words, the error is probably in some place you don't show.

Comment: First make sure that string actually contains the text `C:\\特殊他\\和阿涛和润\\bracket3holes.sat`. Encode your source file as UTF-8 with BOM or as UTF-16. Inspect that string in the debugger. The C++ standard doesn't require support for non-ASCII characters in source code.

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/1968182/ulrich-eckhardt and http://stackoverflow.com/users/4447998/roeland for pointing me in the right direction.  Much to learn...